# Manual citation link with hyperref and natbib

Tags: hyperref, natbib

When one want to do a manual hyperlink to a `\label` target one can use `\hyperref[label]{text}`.

But what if one want to create a link pointing to an item in the bibliography, with a user defined text and the same color as `\cite`

I would rather not have to use `\citealias` all over the place (which might be the right answer, but we are a bit late for that in this project)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hyperref` anchor for `key` is named `cite.key`. It is an anchor, not a label, so you have to use `\hyperlink` instead of `\hyperref`, but that doesn't use the correct link border color etc. In the following, I have instead provided `\hyperlinkcite` for that, for which you just supply the cite `key` and the `link text` as arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
               Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hyperlinkcite}[1]{\hyper@link{cite}{cite.#1}}%\hyperlinkcite takes 2 arguments: #1<- cite-key, #2<- link-text
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\citep{test1}, \hyperlinkcite{test1}{test!}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

(example `bib` file borrowed from elsewhere!)

Be sure that the citation actually gets `\cite`d properly somewhere (or `\nocite`d etc), or it may not show up in the bibliography.

Comment: Slight modification, then it works: `\newcommand*{\hyperlinkcite}[1]{\hyper@link{cite}{cite.#1\@extra@b@citeb}}`, thanks. Without the `\@extra@b@citeb`, I did get the color right, but the target was wrong

Comment: Thanks @daleif. As you say, it does seem to be needed if using certain styles, but I am not entirely confident about the appropriate time to expand `\@extra@b@citeb` (to ensure it expands to the same thing as it did when the anchor was set). Therefore, I will not yet incorporate it into the answer, but assume that anyone for whom the above doesn't work will see your comment!

Comment: I'm trying to redifine my `\cites` command like this: `\citeauthor{#1}'s (\hyper@link{\citeyear{#1}}{cite.#1})` but I'm getting errors everywhere, using `\citeauthor{#1}'s (\hyperlink{cite.#1}{\citeyear{#1}})` works but the hyperlink points to the first page always, and not the actually reference inside the bibliography. Any clues?

Comment: @Felipe: Why are you trying to do that?! You'll be better off asking as a new question.